# Remirror WhitespaceExtension not behaving

Tags: reactjs, prose-mirror, remirror

I'm setting up a basic WYSIWYG editor in Remirror (from scratch, not using the provided `WysiwygEditor`) and I'm running into an issue where the `WhitespaceExtension` doesn't seem to be respecting the default or toggle settings. Everything else seems to work relatively well, starting out.

My assumption is that the `WhitespaceExtension` should be off at the start, but I get this:

[image: There's a whitespace paragraph mark to start even though the toolbar thinks whitespace is toggled off]

[image: Typing shows whitespace invisibles]

Toggling on whitespace in the toolbar has no effect (other than changing the color of the button):

[image: Whitespace toggled on in the toolbar]

I can then toggle whitespace off again:

[image: Whitespace toggled off again in the toolbar]

BUT trying to type immediately after that gives this:

[image: Typing with whitespace toggled (back) off gives mixed whitespace invisibles]

In other words, the toggled-off whitespace stays toggled off, but any new whitespace characters get a placeholder, even though they shouldn't.

I've even tried initializing it with a `WhitespaceOptions` of `{ initialVisibility: false }`, but it doesn't make a difference.

Presumably there's something very obvious I'm either doing or not doing, but I'm not sure what.

Here's the code for the editor:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

import {
    Remirror,
    ThemeProvider,
    useCommands,
    useCurrentSelection,
    useHelpers,
    useRemirror,
} from '@remirror/react';

import {
    BoldExtension, ItalicExtension, UnderlineExtension, StrikeExtension,
    DropCursorExtension,
    FontFamilyExtension, FontSizeExtension, 
    HistoryExtension,
    NodeFormattingExtension,
    TextCaseExtension,
    TrailingNodeExtension,
    WhitespaceExtension,
    YjsExtension
} from 'remirror/extensions';

import {
    Toolbar,
    CommandButton, CommandButtonGroup,
    VerticalDivider,
    HistoryButtonGroup,
    CopyButton, CutButton, PasteButton,
    BasicFormattingButtonGroup, ToggleStrikeButton,
    TextAlignmentButtonGroup, JustifyAlignButton,
    ToggleWhitespaceButton,
} from '@remirror/react-components';

import { FindExtension } from '@remirror/extension-find';

import * as Y from 'yjs';
import { WebrtcProvider } from 'y-webrtc';

import 'remirror/styles/all.css';

import './editor.css';


function MyToolbar() {
    return (
        <Toolbar>
        <HistoryButtonGroup />
        <CommandButtonGroup>
            <CopyButton /><CutButton /><PasteButton />
        </CommandButtonGroup>
        <CommandButtonGroup>
            <BasicFormattingButtonGroup /><ToggleStrikeButton />
        </CommandButtonGroup>
        <CommandButtonGroup>
            <TextAlignmentButtonGroup /><JustifyAlignButton />
        </CommandButtonGroup>
        <CommandButtonGroup>
            <ToggleWhitespaceButton />
        </CommandButtonGroup>
        </Toolbar>
    )
}


export function Editor(props) {

    const ydoc = new Y.Doc();
    // Clients connected to the same roomname share document updates
    const provider = new WebrtcProvider('test-session', ydoc,
        { signaling: ['wss://signaling.yjs.dev', 'wss://y-webrtc-eu.fly.dev'] });

    const {manager, state} = useRemirror({
        extensions: () => [
            new DropCursorExtension(),
            new HistoryExtension(),
            new BoldExtension(),
            new ItalicExtension(),
            new UnderlineExtension(),
            new StrikeExtension(),
            new NodeFormattingExtension(),
            new TrailingNodeExtension(),
            new WhitespaceExtension({ initialVisibility: false }),
            new YjsExtension({ getProvider: () => provider })
        ],
        core: {
            excludeExtensions: ['history']
        },
        selection: 'start'
    });
    
    useEffect(() => {
        // Run once
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <div className="editor-holder">
        <div id="editor" className="editor light-page full-height">
        <ThemeProvider>
        <div className='remirror-theme'>
        <Remirror manager={manager} autoFocus autoRender='end'>
        <MyToolbar />
        </Remirror>
        </div>
        </ThemeProvider>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```